# How can I use fixture elements in exec ? Cypress

Tags: exec, cypress

I m trying to use fixtures element inside exec but  it doesnt work.

cy.exec('ssh  ${this.config.ssh} ${this.config.path} ')

Could you please help me?  Is it possible to use fixture in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import with 'require'
I use fixtures like this: `const quote = require('../fixtures/quote.json')`